# How can I tell when a youtube video's content changes with the youtube API?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a site which allows users to link youtube videos.  We check them all for family friendliness.  However, youtube video creators can trim videos, which means changing the start & end time of a video, changing what's shown.  This type of change can shrink a video, or can be reverted to lengthen a video, or a combination of the two, which could result in an entirely different set of video content.

We want to be able to detect these kind of changes and re-check the video if the actually shown frames have changed.  We cannot simply look at changed durations, because a user could undo a trim and then re-trim to exactly the same length, and we wouldn't notice.  Nor does trimming change the publish date of a video.

We're using the youtube api e.g.:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2CrecordingDetails%2Cstatus&id=[videoId]&key=[apiKey]
```

Which gives us lots of data, including:

```
Duration - this doesn't always change when a video is trimmed (undo trim, trim again)
Title
Etag - this changes all the time
Thumbnails - These don't change when you trim
PublishedAt - this doesn't change when you trim
```

The Etag changing does indicate a change, but it changes too often - any time the title changes, and many other kinds of change, too.  So that would alert us falsely for changes which don't need moderation.

We also thought about grabbing random frames and comparing them over time, but there is no public API for that.

So, how can we use the API to detect that the content of the video has changed?

I am asking here because youtube recommends asking here with the tags I have included in this question: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Also, note that if this problem can't be solved with the existing API, it means that people who submit youtube links to sites can arbitrarily change the content of the video, without the site being able to tell it's changed in a reasonable way.  i.e. Youtube doesn't give consumers a way to verify that the frames & sound within a given videoId don't change.

Comment: "Youtube doesn't give consumers a way to verify that the frames & sound within a given videoId don't change." I can't imagine they (Google) really care all that much. It's a pretty specific niche edge case.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look whether the fileDetails.creationTime property is set? According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#fileDetails.creationTime) this stands for:

> The date and time when the uploaded video file was created.

The recordingDetails.recordingDate property may be of interest too. If these are specified, they are likely to change each time a new upload is made...